# YAHOO Finance API Service is not working for India Stocks

Tags: yahoo-finance, stockquotes

YAHOO Finance api is not working from two days for India stocks. for e.g: http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d?s=ABB.BO+SBI.BO&f=nl1c2vgh&random=10

Is there any way to get live stock updates from Yahoo by Premium or Free?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about the availiability of a service and has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 3):

You can use Yahoo Finance Web service instead, here is an example url to fetch json document, if you do not provide format option in the URL, it will return an XML.

http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/ITC.NS,ITC.BO/quote?format=json

I have tried to use diferrent properties available with the yahoo finance csv api, but I am unable to use them with this api.

**Note:**
*This API doesn't seem to be working anymore*

P.S. Please do not downvote this answer, since it was working fine when the question was asked.

Comment: format=xml is also allowed, only drawback is that it does not show percentage change

Comment: no longer works ?

Answer (score 1):

To fill the gap, I created this [FinanceAPI](https://github.com/neokya/FinanceAPI) - script against Yahoo! Finance India. Feel free to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [link](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130711195331AAoMOCm). They no longer wish to make the service available.